# "Integrated Security not supported" in google apps script jdbc connection

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script

I'm trying to connect to my MS-SQL DB with Google Apps Script using the JDBC function.
We use windows integrated security, but when i try to connect with this parameter i get an error saying that it's not supported.

I've already tried to provide my windows credentials and using the param "IntegratedSecurity=true" but can't connect, tried with server IP and Name but doesn't work either.

```
var address = 'serverIP'; //ex. '10.1.1.1:1433'
var user = ';username=username';
var userPwd = ';password=password';
var db = 'dbname';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address + ';databaseName=' + db;

function readData() {

  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl,user,userPwd);

}
```

I've tried this form too:

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://MyServerIP:1433;databaseName=DBName;integratedSecurity=true");
```

It should connect to the server but all I get is errors

The errors are

In the first form:

> "Unable to connect to a database. Check the connection string,
>   username and password. (line 12, file "Code")"

And in the second form:

> "The following connection properties are not
>   supported: integratedSecurity. (line 13, file "Code")"

Comment: *"all I get is errors"* then share those errors. :)

Comment: Sorry, now i've shared the errors

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for using Windows Integrated Authentication from non-Windows platforms is here: [Using Kerberos integrated authentication to connect to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)  On Windows you have an additional option using a platform .dll as described here: [Connecting with integrated authentication On Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

I have no idea whether either of these is viable in whatever "Google Apps Script" is.

Comment: Hi David! Thanks for the answer but i don't think any of the links apply to my case, GAS (Google Apps Script  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) it's a language very similar to javascript that is used in the google apps like sheets, docs, etc...